# __doPostBack clears all text fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dopostback

I want to call an `ASP.NET` code behind method from `JQuery` and I use it by calling another hidden button `OnClick` attribute.

As you see I have to use `__doPostBack` function which clears all my form inputs after code behind code is done.

Is there a way to prevent emptying my inputs?

Thanx in advance

ASPX:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UniqueID="SubmitBTN" ID="SubmitBTN" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Submit" CssClass="DontShow" />
button type="button" runat="server" onclick="submitfunc()" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

JQuery:

```
function submitfunc() {
     __doPostBack('<%= SubmitBTN.UniqueID %>', '');
}
```

Comment: did you use update panels??

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

wrap your contents with Update Panels as Shown below or You can make Ajax Calls Using Jquery

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManger1" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UniqueID="SubmitBTN" ID="SubmitBTN" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Submit" CssClass="DontShow" />
<button type="button" runat="server" onclick="submitfunc()" class="submit">Submit</button>

  </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change values using javascript/jquery or anything client side the new values don't interact with the ViewState. Therefore when the page reloads the original values are restored from the ViewState

Solution
store your values in hidden field and then restore it.